# How to add a JScrollPanel to previously added label components?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

I'm having a little problem when
trying to add JScrollPanel to previously added components
with their bounds set specificaly in the for loop. The problem begins when I wanna add more than 15 components in my frame because I've explicitly set frame height and width so they won't be visible.
Here is a code snippet:

```
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setResizable(false);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        for(int i=0,j=0;i<questions.length;i++) {

            JLabel quest = new JLabel((i+1)+") "+questions[i][0]);
            quest.setBounds(185, 10+j, 200, 200);
            contentPane.add(quest);

            JLabel ans = new JLabel("Ans) "+answers[i][0]);
            ans.setBounds(190, 30+j, 200, 200);
            contentPane.add(ans);
            j=j+40;

        }

        Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.setBounds(270, 530, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(Exit);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

The code from above consists of for loop where I dynamically add components
to their preferred x, y location using setBounds and simple exit button. How can I add JLabel components (quest, ans) from loop to JScrollPanel but to keep their location as specified in for loop ?

Thanks guys for all the previous help :)

Comment: A JScrollPane will not work when you use setBounds() and a null layout. Swing components are designed to be used with layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and let the layout manager set the size and location, then the scroll pane will work as expected. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: *"Here is a code snippet:"* 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). A `null` layout will *especially* screw with scroll panes. ..

Comment: .. In this case, better to add the panel to the scroll pane when it is constructed, and specify a vertical scroll-bar 'as needed'. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.